# Why is my LWC Datatable editable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have created a Lightning Web Component (LWC) that includes a Datatable. Despite setting 'show-row-number-column' to false, the column is still visible and not useful as only one digit is displayed correctly (1-9 is good, after that it's only the first digit).

[image: Faulty row number]

I have tried making all columns non-editable, as I read that making a row editable enforces the column to be visible, but the column is still there. I suspect that another element, such as the button that allows the user to change the width, is making the table editable. Can anyone think of what it might be, or how I can at help me fix the numbers?

// HTML

```
<lightning-datatable
                column-widths-mode="auto"
                columns={columns}
                data={filesList}
                hide-checkbox-column="true"
                key-field="id"
                onrowaction={handleOnRowAction}
                onsort={handleOnSort}
                row-number-offset="0"
                show-row-number-column="false"
                sorted-by={sortedBy}
                sorted-direction={sortDirection}
></lightning-datatable>
```

// Columns

```
[
    {
        initialWidth: 50,
        cellAttributes: {
            style: '--lwc-squareIconUtilitySmall: 1.75rem;',
            iconName: {fieldName: 'iconName'}

        },
        editable: false
    },
    {
        label: 'Dateiname',
        fieldName: 'title',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true,
        editable: false,
        wrapText: true,

    },
    {
        label: 'Größe',
        fieldName: 'contentSize',
        initialWidth: 90,
        sortable: true,
        type: "Text",
        editable: false
    },
    {
        label: 'Datum',
        fieldName: 'contentModifiedDate',
        type: 'date',
        sortable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "2-digit",
            day: "2-digit",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
            timeZone: LOCALE
        },
        initialWidth: 122,
        editable: false
    },
    {
        type: 'button', fixedWidth: 130, typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Vorschau',
            name: 'view_file',
            variant: 'outline-brand',
            iconName: 'utility:preview'
        },
        editable: false
    },
    {
        type: 'button',
        fixedWidth: 150,
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'Download',
            name: 'download_file',
            variant: 'outline-brand',
            iconName: 'utility:download'
        },
        editable: false
    }
];
```